# Using a specific figure handler in Pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

Say I have a dataframe and I do a boxplot:

```
f = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
df.boxplot(column='a', by='b')
f.tight_layout()
```

When running the last statement I get:

```
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

It looks like `df.boxplot` creates its own figure. Is this correct? If so, how can I retrieve the handle of the figure that Pandas creates?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ax` keyword argument as below in the [`boxplot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html) method

```
f = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
a = f.add_subplot(1,1,1)

df.boxplot(column='a', by='b', ax=a)
f.tight_layout()
```

Comment: Thanks. I also noticed that Pandas `boxplot` uses its own title. But even if I do `ax.set_title('My title')` it doesn't fully change it. It's as if there were two titles. Do you know happen to know how to change it?

Comment: You can use `plt.suptitle("")` as per [here](http://blog.th4t.net/get-rid-of-the-automatic-pandas-generated-boxplot-title.html)